# Changing text based on view AngularJS error

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out why a script I'm using is giving an error. I have two pages on my application and I would like some header text to change when the view is switched. It works in its current form, but I keep getting a console error which I'd like to fix. Here is the code:

```
.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });
```

And then in my HTML:

```
<h1 class="section-intro" ng-bind="title"></h1>
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at app.js:39
    at Scope.$broadcast (angular.js:16165)
    at angular-route.js:619
    at processQueue (angular.js:14567)
    at angular.js:14583
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15846)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15657)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15951)
    at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:12086)
    at HTMLBodyElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (jquery.js:4435)
```

Which has something to do with:

```
   $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
```

I'm mostly confused because the script works, but the error is being thrown when I switched back and fourth.

Comment: In your view it'd be `$root.title` not just `title`. Also, double `$$` between current and route? `$$` is reserved for private variables.

Comment: How do you define title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be simple fix, just use `current.title` instead of private `$$route` object. `current` route is going to inherit `title`:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.title;
    });
}]);
```